# How to make buttons fill vertically in a NSStackView with a fixed height

Tags: macos, interface-builder, nsstackview

[image]

The NSStackView shown above has top/leading/trailing constraints, a proportional height to its superview, and is set to Align Top and Fill Equally. I want to have the buttons stretch vertically to fill the height of their stack view. How can I configure this with a NSStackView? Or do I have to add constraints on the buttons?

Comment: Set align = .fill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by setting top/bottom constraints on the buttons to the stack view. I don't think there is a way to configure an NSStackView to do what I want.

So a UIButton fills the height of the UIStackView if the UIStackView's alignment is set to fill. An NSStackView does not have a fill property for alignment and AFAIK, can't make an NSButton do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, it's not possible using `NSStackView`. It lacks fill alignment, available for `UIStackView`.

However, there is a much more powerful UI component in AppKit:

`NSGridView` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsgridview

You can customize alignment for each row and column, including "fill" mode.